# Upload a file form google drive in Core Php and retrieve it on local

Tags: php

I want to Upload a file form google drive in Core Php and retrieve it on local which is select from a google drive. In which I need a code for a select a specific file from google drive and upload it in local. I don't have an idea for a code so make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create filepicker.php file and write below mentioned code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Google Drive File Picker Example</title>
    <style>
    .button {
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 0px;
      width: 150px;
      height: 35px;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" class="button" style="vertical-align:middle" id="pick" style="bgcolor:blue;"><span align="center"><img src="Google_Drive.png"  height="20px"> Google Drive</span></button>
        <script src="filepicker.js"></script>
        <?php 
        echo "<script> function hi() {   alert('hi') } </script>";
        echo "<button type='button' onclick='hi()'> click </button>";
        ?>
        <script>
            function initPicker() {
                var picker = new FilePicker({
                    apiKey: 'AIzaSyB2c-5sNr6U4VpbIgvcDUHsnSwqT8ia0sM',
                    clientId: '649363830487-g2bckoufvgpeme8r5a9jngdp6c509mnq',
                    buttonEl: document.getElementById('pick'),
                    onSelect: function(file) {
                    console.log(file);
                    var fid = file.id;
            //      document.write('Selected ' + file.title + '<br>');
                    var temp = 'drive.google.com/file/d/' + fid;
                    var url = document.write('<b>Selected: </b> ' + 'drive.google.com/file/d/' + fid + '<br>');
                    alert(temp);

                    document.write("<a href='//"+temp+"'/> Click</a>");
                    }   
                }); 
            }
        </script> 

        <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyB2c-5sNr6U4VpbIgvcDUHsnSwqT8ia0sM"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=initPicker"></script>

        <?php 
        ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Then create js file named as filepicker.js

```
/**!
 * Google Drive File Picker Example
 * By Daniel Lo Nigro (http://dan.cx/)
 */
(function() {
    /**
     * Initialise a Google Driver file picker
     */

    var FilePicker = window.FilePicker = function(options) {
        // Config
        this.apiKey = options.apiKey;
        this.clientId = options.clientId;

        // Elements
        this.buttonEl = options.buttonEl;

        // Events
        this.onSelect = options.onSelect;
        this.buttonEl.addEventListener('click', this.open.bind(this));      

        // Disable the button until the API loads, as it won't work properly until then.
        this.buttonEl.disabled = true;

        // Load the drive API
        gapi.client.setApiKey(this.apiKey);
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', this._driveApiLoaded.bind(this));
        google.load('picker', '1', { callback: this._pickerApiLoaded.bind(this) });
}

    FilePicker.prototype = {
        /**
         * Open the file picker.
         */
        open: function() {      
            // Check if the user has already authenticated
            var token = gapi.auth.getToken();
            if (token) {
                this._showPicker();
            } else {
                // The user has not yet authenticated with Google
                // We need to do the authentication before displaying the Drive picker.
                this._doAuth(false, function() { this._showPicker(); }.bind(this));
            }
        },

        /**
         * Show the file picker once authentication has been done.
         * @private
         */
        _showPicker: function() {
            var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
            this.picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
                addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCUMENTS).
                setAppId(this.clientId).
                setOAuthToken(accessToken).
                setCallback(this._pickerCallback.bind(this)).
                build().
                setVisible(true);
        },

        /**
         * Called when a file has been selected in the Google Drive file picker.
         * @private
         */
        _pickerCallback: function(data) {
            if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
                var file = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0],
                    id = file[google.picker.Document.ID],
                    request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
                        fileId: id
                    });

                request.execute(this._fileGetCallback.bind(this));
            }
        },
        /**
         * Called when file details have been retrieved from Google Drive.
         * @private
         */
        _fileGetCallback: function(file) {
            if (this.onSelect) {
                this.onSelect(file);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Called when the Google Drive file picker API has finished loading.
         * @private
         */
        _pickerApiLoaded: function() {
            this.buttonEl.disabled = false;
        },

        /**
         * Called when the Google Drive API has finished loading.
         * @private
         */
        _driveApiLoaded: function() {
            this._doAuth(true);
        },

        /**
         * Authenticate with Google Drive via the Google JavaScript API.
         * @private
         */
        _doAuth: function(immediate, callback) {    
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                client_id: this.clientId + '.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                immediate: immediate
            }, callback);
        }
    };

}());
```

Comment: This answer will definitely solve your problem of uploading file and retrieve via google drive.